# API decode a Base64 encoded file received via ReadAsMultipartAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have an API that receives a 150K encoded (base64) video file that I save on the hard disk using this code:

```
var provider = new Base64MultipartFileStreamProvider("C:\\sample.avi");
await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider);
```

My goal is to decode it before I save it to disk so I use a personalized provider **Base64MultipartFileStreamProvider: MultipartFileStreamProvider** and override the GetStream method as this:

```
public override Stream GetStream(HttpContent parent, HttpContentHeaders headers)
{    
   Collection<MultipartFileData> _fileData = new Collection<MultipartFileData>();
   MultipartFileData fileData = new MultipartFileData(headers, fullPath);
   _fileData.Add(fileData);

   var stream = File.Create(fullPath, 0x1000, FileOptions.Asynchronous);
   return new CryptoStream(stream, new FromBase64Transform(), 
                           CryptoStreamMode.Write);
}
```

This saves the received file as C:\sample.avi but the file still remains base64 encoded.

**Question:**
What's the right way to decode the file before saving it on the hard drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write your own StreamProvider, it's easiest to start from the file stream provider.

**This is just a sketch, up to you to make it work**

And when you get the file stream, wrap it with a cryptostream before writing it to a file:

Here is a rough sketch, use the provider below instead of the one in your example:

```
public class Base64MultiPartFileStreamProvider : MultipartFormDataStreamProvider
{
    public Base64MultiPartFileStreamProvider(string path) : base(path)
    {
    }

    public override Stream GetStream(HttpContent parent, HttpContentHeaders headers)
    {
       var stream = base.GetStream(parent, headers);

      ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition = headers.ContentDisposition;
      if (contentDisposition != null)
      {
          if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentDisposition.FileName))
          {
              stream = new CryptoStream(stream, new FromBase64Transform(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
          }
      }

      return stream;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain better the wrapping it ...what's the need for that?

Comment: You want to get at the raw stream and decode it, the default provider doesn't let you do that. So this way the provider writes to the crypto stream that decodes it and writes it into the file stream.

Comment: Note, I just sketched it. Haven't really compiled and debugged it :) I'm leaving it up to you.

Comment: I know..I know ... :--) Thanks a lot. I'll let u know.

Comment: The crypto thing ...are u referring to change the 2nd line to something like this: var stream = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider); and then use your line?

Comment: Sorry no, I'll edit. The second line was just to highlight the change inside the provider.

Comment: Somehow, it is NOT decoding the file.

Comment: I just verified with a slightly modified provider that it works. I updated the answer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52344/discussion-between-yishai-galatzer-and-eager-to-learn)

Comment: It's saving the file as decoded, but somehow I cannot play that file as video (even if the client file can). I don't see anything strange on your code. Not sure what could be the problem

Comment: I was wondering if you think it's a good idea (or recommended) to actually develop a WebAPI2 FileUpload method that EXPECTS the file to be BASE64 encoded??

Comment: I wouldn't choose a base64 file as input to begin with, and will convert it on the client if possible. But if it's not possible, there is nothing wrong with that.